# Remove last tab of jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am a bit confused, because I can't remove the last Tab of my JTabbedPane.
I read this two questions:
[first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013479/after-calling-jtabbedpane-removeall-the-jtabbedpane-still-has-x-number-of-tab)  and [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013479/after-calling-jtabbedpane-removeall-the-jtabbedpane-still-has-x-number-of-tab). But it didnt helped to me.
This is how my code looks like:

```
public void updateTabbedPane()
{
    // Remove the MouseListener
    tabbedPane.removeMouseListener(tabbedPaneMouseListener);

    // Remove all Tabs
    while (tabbedPane.getTabCount() > 0)
    {
        tabbedPane.remove(0);
    }

    // Sort the ArrayList
    Collections.sort(arrayList);

    // Add all Element to the JTabbedPane
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
    {
        tabbedPane.addTab(arrayList.get(i).getName(),
                new JScrollPane(...);
    }

    // Add the MouseListiner to the JTabbedPane again
    tabbedPane.addMouseListener(tabbedPaneMouseListener);
}
```

I am using this method to add/remove a tab if an object was added/removed to the list. I also sort the ArrayList, because I want to have the tabs in an ascending order.

As said in the answers of the two questions, I removed the MouseListener before I remove the Tabs, but the last Tab is still visible in the end. I also tried to setVisible(), removeAll().

Any help is welcome!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The questions cited are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your advices at Andrew Thompson and Andrew Mao.

@Mao: 1.) I am using the Swing GUI Thread. 2.) `setVisible` was just my last idea of fixing my problem :-P 3.) Of course in this way it would be more performant, but in this case I was a little bit dirty, because there wouldn't be more then three tabs at the same time. But I think I'm going to change it later on.

@Thompson: Because of the SSCCE, I created a project just for my problem (which you can see down below), to show my problem. But this project worked, so I compare the little steps of my test project with my real project and found a little mistake.

My problem was that I updated the tabs, before I removed the object of the `ArrayList`, so the GUI still showed the removed Object as a tab.

For anyone who is interested in my `JTabbedPane` test project:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TabbedTest extends JFrame {

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = null;
    private MouseListener tabbedPaneMouseListener = null;
    private ArrayList<String> nameOfTab = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static int counter = 1;

    public TabbedTest() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton addButton = new JButton("add");
        addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addElementToArrayList();
            }
        });
        JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");
        removeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                removeElementFromArrayList();
            }
        });

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPaneMouseListener = (new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Do Something");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        tabbedPane.addMouseListener(tabbedPaneMouseListener);

        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(removeButton);
        add(buttonPanel);
        this.add(tabbedPane);
    }

    private void addElementToArrayList() {
        nameOfTab.add("" + counter++ + ". element");
        updateTabbedPane();
    }

    private void removeElementFromArrayList() {
        if (nameOfTab.size() > 0) {
            nameOfTab.remove(0);
        }
        updateTabbedPane();
    }

    public void updateTabbedPane() {
        tabbedPane.removeMouseListener(tabbedPaneMouseListener);
        while (tabbedPane.getTabCount() > 0) {
            tabbedPane.remove(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nameOfTab.size(); i++) {
            tabbedPane.addTab(nameOfTab.get(i), new JLabel(nameOfTab.get(i)));
        }
        tabbedPane.addMouseListener(tabbedPaneMouseListener);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TabbedTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to focus on a problem. For safety, use the `@Override` annotation. Note that people addressed in an answer won't be notified.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you may not be running this code in [Swing's GUI thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html). Is it inside a `Runnable` that is passed to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`? `removeAll` should work if that is the case.

Also, you shouldn't be using `setVisible` on components directly - you should be using `setSelectedIndex` or `setSelectedComponent` on the `JTabbedPane`.

Moreover, removing all the tabs and creating a new `JScrollPane` again for all but one of them seems horribly inefficient when the total order of the tabs doesn't change. Perhaps you should maintain a list in sorted order, such as a `TreeSet`, and just insert and remove a single tab at the appropriate index when there is an update.